# How to pass parameters from specific view to _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-core, layout, partial-views

I have a tool site, and the site layout was arranged like below. Black square has the main content, and when you go to a specific tool now I want to display the related tools on the right side.

[image]

Now to avoid Col-md duplication on every page I arranged the Layout page like this

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <main role="main" class="pb-3">
                    @RenderBody()
                </main>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                //Related tools widget
            </div>
        </div>
```

So inside above code the  I want to display this related tools widget. But there is a condition. When you go to a specific tool, that specific tool should not be displayed in that widget. So I created a partial view, and now I don't know where to call it.

How to achieve that?
Is my structure all right? Instead of using col-md on the layout shall I use them on a specific view like the one below?

```
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
               //Content goes here
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
               @RenderSection("RelatedTools", required:true)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have using `@RenderSection("RelatedTools", required:true)`,you need to add `@section RelatedTools {}` in your each view:

Layout:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <main role="main" class="pb-3">
                    @RenderBody()
                </main>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @RenderSection("RelatedTools", required:true)
            </div>
        </div>
       
    </div>
```

View:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

@section RelatedTools {
    <div><h1>RelatedTools</h1></div>
}
```

So that the html in `@section RelatedTools` will in the right side,and the html outside `@section RelatedTools` will in the left side.

Result:
[image]